# Temporarily/Dynamically disable single page in Viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I have an extended FragmentPagerAdapter that provides 3 fragments to a ViewPager, giving me 3 pages that I can either swipe between or use the tabs I've added to the actionbar to manually choose a page.

I'd like to temporarily disable the user from accessing the final page (a more generalized solution to disable any specific page would also be interesting, but not necessary) with either navigation type. I will then re-enable their access with a callback from one of the fragments.

I've read through answers to some similar questions about not allowing swiping by overriding onTouchEvent and onInterceptTouchEvent, and then using some custom gesture detection within those, or even a half solution using beginFakeDrag().

My current solution simply sets a smaller item count in the adapter, making sure to use notifyDataSetChanged(), and changes it back when necessary. Are there any elegant alternatives to these approaches, maybe one that doesn't require changing the dataset?

I also see that ActionBar.Tab doesn't have a setEnable() method, and most suggest to just remove the tab. Is there a way I can have a tab remain visible but not selectable? My approach has been to define which tab is disabled and reselect the previously selected tab if the user selects the disabled one.

**Edit:** I aim to disable both tabbing and swiping to the last page.

Comment: Why not just switch the layout of the last tab to something the user can't interact with? `ViewPager` is not really suited for those needs. Yes, you can use it dynamically by changing the dataset, but it's easier to block your tab ui than change the behaviour of a `ViewPager`.

Comment: Well, I'm not really looking for easier. I'm using both tabs and swiping for navigation. I have working solutions for both issues; I just wanted to seek other suggestions that might be packaged better.

Comment: But you're right in any case, blocking interaction with the page is definitely a viable solution.

Comment: Well you also have to consider that a user isn't really used to blocked tab pages on Android devices. So unless you make the behaviour absolutely clear to him, it might seem to him that your app isn't working properly, because tabs are all accessible in general. I personally am always a bit confused when I see disabled buttons that don't do anything when I click them or other curious stuff. My first thoughts are always "Is it working properly or is it a bug?". So perhaps it might be better to use another ui solution.

Comment: That's a very good point. Ultimately, that part of the question comes down to user feedback and I will consider all possibilities for my final solution. That being said, the question still stands as is, and whether it confuses the user will be decided before anything is finalized. As a sidenote, I am already considering just removing the tab until the final page is enabled.

Answer (score 6):

You're definitely going to want to create your own custom ViewPager subclass. I created a simple custom `ViewPager` called `CustomSwipePager` that will handle blocking user interaction when needed.

```
public class CustomSwipeViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private boolean mLastPageEnabled = false;
    private int mLastPageIndex = 0;

    public NoSwipeViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NoSwipeViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setLastPageEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        mLastPageEnabled = enabled;
    }

    public void setLastPageIndex(int index) {
        mLastPageIndex = index;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

        if(!mLastPageEnabled && getCurrentItem() >= (mLastPageIndex - 1)) {
            // Always return false to disable user swipes
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        if (!mLastPageEnabled && getCurrentItem() >= (mLastPageIndex - 1)) {
            // Always return false to disable user swipes
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

There are two key methods you will want to take advantage of in the class `setLastPageEnabled()` and `setLastPageIndex()`. You can set the last page index to whatever you need, in your case if you have three items you would set it to 2. Then also use `setLastPageEnabled(false)` to disable swiping or to re-enabled use `setLastPageEnabled(true)`.

You can include this custom view into your layout like this:

```
<com.mypackage.CustomSwipeViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/custom_swipe_view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And finally reference it in your Fragment or Activity in the appropriate place:

```
private CustomSwipeViewPager mPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mPager = (CustomSwipeViewPager) findViewById(R.id.custom_swipe_view_pager);
    mPager.setLastPageEnabled(false);
    mPager.setLastPageIndex(2);
}
```

Comment: This is similar to the solution I referenced in my question, where you override onTouchEvent and onTouchInterceptEvent. Very clean implementation. The part this solution is missing is detecting the direction of the gesture to still allow swiping back to previous pages from the penultimate page. I will include my code for this if I decide to go this route.

Comment: As @einschnaehkeee implied in his comment, it's kind of a hacked use of ViewPager, but I considered other options already and decided this functionality fit my use case the best. I guess I was hoping I had missed something obvious.

Comment: I guess the only other option would be adding/removing the last page as needed. At that point you might want to consider a change in UI though. Perhaps that last page doesn't even belong in the ViewPager, I am unfamiliar with your design though

Comment: Yes, I have considered other UI options. The use of mobile software for this purpose is already fairly unique, so I've had to do a lot of deciding on whether to stick with Android API components or redesign a lot. But I do have reasons why I currently want the page in the ViewPager; I just figured they were irrelevant to the posted question since that's one of the assumptions. Thanks for your advice.